# create a 3D array of square matrices in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to vectorize the creation of a set of 2x2 arrays,
so I've written the following code

```
import numpy as np
# an array of parameters
a = np.array(( 1.0, 10.0, 100.0))
# create a set of 2x2 matrices
b = np.array((( 1*a, 2*a), ( 3*a, 4*a)))

# to access the 2x2 matrix, I can do as follows
for i in range(3):
    print(i,"\n",b[:,:,i])
```

whose output is

> ```
> 0 
>  [[ 1.  2.]
>  [ 3.  4.]]
> 1 
>  [[ 10.  20.]
>  [ 30.  40.]]
> 2 
>  [[ 100.  200.]
>  [ 300.  400.]]
> ```

so far, so good, but what I'd really like is creating `b` in some different
manner, so that I could reference the 2x2 matrices simply by

```
b = ...
# this code doesn't work!
for i in range(3):
    print(i,"\n",b[i])
```

thanks in advance,
                                                            g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [`numpy.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html); for your example:

```
>>> b.transpose(2, 0, 1)
array([[[   1.,    2.],
        [   3.,    4.]],

       [[  10.,   20.],
        [  30.,   40.]],

       [[ 100.,  200.],
        [ 300.,  400.]]])
>>> b.transpose(2, 0, 1)[0]
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.]])
```

Comment: I can instantiate `b` as follows

Comment: [My apologies for the previous aborted comment] That's OK: I can instantiate `b` as follows `b = np.array( ... ).transpose(2,0,1)` and later access individual 2D arrays as I please. I cannot vote up your answer (no reputation...) but I wish I could!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
>>> b = np.array([1,2,3,4]).reshape((2,2)) * np.ones((3,2,2)) * np.array([1,10,100])[...,None,None]

>>> for i in range(3):
...     print i,"\n",b[i]
0 
[[ 1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.]]
1 
[[ 10.  20.]
 [ 30.  40.]]
2 
[[ 100.  200.]
 [ 300.  400.]]
```